# Django 1.9 Find object in list that has attribute equal to some value

Tags: python, django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I wondering thinking how can i do a query for all Restaurants that have the attribute equal to some given value, and other given value in a list of delivery zones attribute.
Here is how looks my code:

models.py

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    delivery_zones = models.ManyToManyField('DeliveryZone', default=None)
    service_type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=settings.SERVICE_TYPE_CHOICES, default='DELIVERY')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class DeliveryZones(models.Model):
    zone = models.CharField(max_length=25, default=None)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py:

```
restaurants = get_list_404(
    Restaurant, is_active=True,
    service_type='SOME_GIVEN_SERVICE_TYPE_NAME',
    delivery_zones__icontains='SOME_GIVEN_ZONE_NAME'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you are looking for is the `__in` lookup. Also, it is `get_list_or_404`, not `get_list_404`.

Try:

```
zones = DeliveryZones.objects.filter(zone='SOME_NAME', is_active=True)
restaurants = get_list_or_404(
    Restaurant, is_active=True,
    service_type='SOME_GIVEN_SERVICE_TYPE_NAME',
    delivery_zones__in=zones
)
```

Comment: Great! If this solved the problem, be sure to press the "Check" mark on the left of my answer so that anyone that needs help will know the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single query, which means a single database hit, by using a [lookup that spans a relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
restaurants = get_list_or_404(
    Restaurant, is_active=True,
    service_type='SOME_GIVEN_SERVICE_TYPE_NAME',
    delivery_zones__name='SOME_GIVEN_ZONE_NAME'
)
```

This will be much more efficient, especially if the possible list of `DeliveryZones` is quite long.